# delete flutter emulator

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code, android-emulator

i created a flutter emulator using VsCode and now have two emulators on my computer.
running `emulator -list-avds` gives

```
Pixel_3_API_27
flutter_emulator
```

i would like to delete the `flutter_emulator` instance and be left with only `Pixel_3_API_27` since i can't even run it using `emulator -avd flutter_emulator`
tried using android studio but it's not displayed there. How can i delete it since i created it from vscode run debug menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For windows, Go to

```
C:\user\username.android\avd
```

For Mac,

```
/Users/pratikbutani/.android/avd
```

delete the folder and restart the IDE.